# how do you check if a textarea has been edited on an asp.net page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, forms

I've got a page with multiple steps to completing a form. In each step, a different partial view is loaded. One step is a textbox. They can come back and edit it at a later date, and I want it to pop up a window asking if they want to save it when they go to a different step without saving what they have done, but only if they have edited what is in the textbox. Is there a simple way to do this using javascript or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use javascript to check if the textbox is "dirty"](http://sim.plified.com/2008/05/07/dirty-dirty-dirty-implementing-isdirty-with-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a counter variable on a page that is set to 0. Now attach an onchange event to the text box. everytime the onchange event fires increment the counter variable. now when user navigates to a different page check if the counter variable is 0. if it is 0 then text box has not been edited otherwise the user has edited the text box.

---

**a better approach** 
on page load(`window.onload`) store the text(`textbox.value`) of the text box you want to monitor in a variable. when user navigates to other page check if the current text of the text box matches the variable's text then the *text box's value is unchanged(however it might have been edited more than one time)*
its a better approach because there are just 2 extra javascript calls one on page load and the other when user attempts page navigation.
In the previous approach every time the textbox's text changes there is a javascript call(onchange event and incremnting counter variable)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the value has change from when the page loaded, you can compare the current value to the *defaultValue*:

```
if (textArea.defaultValue != textArea.value) {

  // It's been edited

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try [dirtyField](http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/dirtyFields/documentation.cfm) plug-in. [Here](http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/dirtyFields/examples.cfm) are some example using drityField.